# Using Mathf.SmoothDamp() in a coroutine takes longer than expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm using SmoothDamp in a co-routine to gradually resize a character collider as the character plays a crouch animation:

```
void OnRifleIdleToCrouchStart(){
    float idleToCrouchVelocity = -0.01f;
    IEnumerator idleToCrouchColl = smoothHeightChange(idleToCrouchVelocity, 1.45f, 1.2f, 0.38f); //smoothTime is .38 since speed for idle to crouch is 2
    StartCoroutine(idleToCrouchColl);
}

IEnumerator smoothHeightChange(float idleToCrouchVelocity, float targetHeight, float targetCenterY, float smoothTime){
    Debug.Log("smoothHeightChange START " + Time.time);
    while(Math.Round(controller.height, 2) > targetHeight)
    {
        float idleToCrouchVelocityCenter = idleToCrouchVelocity * -1f;
        float newHeight = Mathf.SmoothDamp(controller.height, targetHeight, ref idleToCrouchVelocity, smoothTime);
        float newCenterY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(controller.center.y, targetCenterY, ref idleToCrouchVelocityCenter, smoothTime);
        controller.height = newHeight;
        controller.center = new Vector3(controller.center.x, newCenterY, controller.center.z);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    Debug.Log("smoothHeightChange FINISH " + Time.time);
}
```

I expected the crouch to take the length of smoothTime (.38 seconds) but comparing the start and end times shows it actually takes around 2 seconds. I suspect this is because I'm waiting for the end of each frame in the coroutine, and SmoothDamp assumes its being done every frame. So my smoothDamp value needs to actually be smaller than .38 proportional to the time left in each frame over the course of the animation. But I'm not sure what value I should modify smoothDamp by, as the frame timing is likely different each frame over the course of the animation (~40 frames). How do I refactor the coroutine takes the length of smoothDamp to complete?

Thanks!

Comment: Why `idleToCrouchVelocity = -0.01f;`? Did you try `0` instead?